# How to run xmr-stak with AMD gpu on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, ubuntu, xmr-stak

I have tried several attempts but without success. AMDGPU-PRO 17.40, 17.50, Oibaf PPA and something more, but nothing makes clinfo gives right results and xmr-stak working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 does for sure work with amdgpu-pro 18.20 on xmr-stak for cryptonight v7. Been running it for couple weeks, not saying it's easy but it works. I could be coerced into giving the details, but I am plenty busy already. Maybe it's because I've been a linux dev since '91. I think the xmr-stak devs should bump up to 3% donation by default. They're doing a great job.

Comment: Seems churlish to be a stackexchanger and say "....I could be coerced, but I'm too busy because I'm this super duper linux dev for longer than most of you have been alive". Seriously, dude? Why are you even here? To gloat? To participate but not contribute? I've tried Ubuntu 18.04 and several different AMD drivers (but NOT the 18.20 version), and never managed to get xmr-stak to work. I can consistently get Ubuntu 16.0.4, AMD SDK, and AMD GPU driver 18.10-572953 (not the PRO installation, just the regular driver) to compile XMR-STAK (including the latest 2.5.1). More than happy to share the in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the latest **Radeon Software for Linux** driver, the [18.50](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-lin-18-50-unified) version, I was able to make xmr-stak working without issues.

Answer (score 2):

The AMD drivers are indeed frustrating on Linux, but these are required by XMR-Stak for AMD cards. You will almost certainly need to download the official drivers from AMD and try the various releases until you find one that works with your specific card. For me, this was only amdgpu-pro-17.40.**2712-510357**, but it depends which card you have. There are several minor point releases and finding one that works is honestly trial and error unfortunatley.

The other issue you may face is that you are on Ubuntu 18.04 - and none of the currently released drivers state supporting Ubuntu 18.04, you might get lucky though.

Comment: I wasn't able to make the 17.40 working and I got only 'invalid shares' error with the 18.20. Trying with the latest 18.50, it seems working without issues for now.

Comment: As I mentioned, it depends on what card you have. It really is a case of trial and error till you find a driver that works with your specific card.

Answer (score 1):

You need the 18.20 drivers for Ubuntu 18.04 https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-18.20-Early-Preview-Release-Notes.aspx

Comment: I got only 'invalid shares' with the 18.20.

Answer (score 1):

18.20 drivers didnt work for me... I could mine cryptonight lite and heavy but no way cryptonight v7. Downgrading drivers back to 17.* solved this issue but still i belive xmr-stak worked better with ubuntu 16.* and 17.* series. I belive except drivers issue there is also some issue related with 4.15/4.16 kernels. With 4.15.* my cards randomly crash (one day one card, another day another one... withouth any pattern) and with 4.16.* it is even worse.